# VM in virtualbox is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)

Tags: virtualbox

My VM in virtualbox can not start due to this error, I don't want to destroy it and reinstall it again, anyway to recover it ?

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

```
Command: ["modifyvm", "319fcce3-e8ff-4b6f-a641-3aee1df6543f", "--natpf1", "delete", "ssh"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The machine 'centos64_c6402_1454036461345_59755' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 493 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

Answer (score 182):

Running this on the command line unlocked the VM:

```
vboxmanage startvm <vm-uuid> --type emergencystop
```

Where `<vm-uuid>` is the number in the error message: `Command: ["modifyvm", "<vm-uuid>" [...]`. After that I was able to control the VM (start, halt, etc).
Using Virtualbox 4.1 on Ubuntu.

Comment: thanx man, this really helped me, I had some issues regarding a shared folder in docker. I couldn't delete the shared folder (error: Could not find a shared folder named 'ourspends'), and also, upon creating, it was saying that it already exists (Could not create a shared folder 'ourspends' mapped to '/home/relu/projects/ourspends' (VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS))

Comment: Where do I run this exactly? Obviously, this is not from within the VM itself, as the "vboxmanage" command relates to the VBox software on the hosting machine and the VM itself doesn't recognize this. On the other hand, this command is unknow also to my hosting machine (in my case, it's Windows 10). So... what do I need to run this command then?

Comment: I executed it in a terminal using Linux. I guess that in Windows it can be executed in a Command Prompt (cmd). It was tested with VirtualBox 4.1

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm. Should be accept as answer.

Comment: Grande Gonza!! Jaja :)

Comment: Use *VBoxManage -nologo list vms* to find out your vm-uuid

Comment: For Windows you need the full path so run `"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" <vm-uuid> --type emergencystop`

Comment: Worked without any issues. One thing is we can fetch the vm id from the previously observed error itself.

Comment: This is the best way that works for me. I want to add that to find the uuid of the VM, use this command (edit path if necessary):  
```"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" -nologo list vms```

Answer (score 39):

Having the same issue I found that there was a process running actually locking the vm:

```
501 79419 79323   0  2:18PM ??         0:39.75 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless --comment default --startvm 1d438a2e-68d7-4ba2-bef9-4ea162913c1b --vrde config
```

Make sure you don't have a process stuck trying to start the vm:

```
ps -ef | grep -i "vbox"
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I killed all processes returned by the ps -ef statement and then "vagrant destroy" worked again.

Answer (score 17):

I found this answer from @Gonzalez very interesting.

```
vboxmanage startvm <vm-uuid> --type emergencystop
```

The only problem with that it shut down the current instance of my VM, so instead of using `modifyvm` you can use `controlvm` if the current vm is running.

For example:

```
 VBoxManage modifyvm <vm_name> --natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,22,,2222"
 VBoxManage modifyvm <vm_name> --natpf1 delete "guestssh"
```

Become:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm_name> natpf1 "guestssh,tcp,,22,,2222"
VBoxManage controlvm <vm_name> natpf1 delete "guestssh"
```

Full documentation Here
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-controlvm

Comment: VBoxManage controlvm "Ubuntu_1604s" --natpf1 "u8848,tcp,,18848,,8848"
But i got error same as modifyvm 

error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Shared)" at line 388 of file VBoxManageControlVM.cpp

are there any solutions?

Answer (score 17):

`sudo pkill -9 VBox` kills everything running related to vbox

Comment: That's a really bad idea as it kills all guests if you have more than one, and doesn't even give them a chance to shut down everything, so may very well result in data loss.

Comment: I can't even imagine who would give this an up-vote. Having more than one guest running would most certainly leave those in a undefined state, with a high chance of resulting in loss of data and control.

Comment: The **correct** answer is `vboxmanage startvm <vm-uuid> --type emergencystop` as stated by @Gonzalo Matheu and @Erman

Answer (score 16):

For me I had to kill the VboxHeadless.exe process in task manager.  I also had to ensure CMD prompt was opened in Administrative mode.

Comment: Worked also for me using Linux. Advise to gracefully shut down all other VMs also running (can use `ps aux | grep box` if in the terminal).

Answer (score 8):

In Windows Task Manager, I ended any tasks related to Virtual Box (you can see they start with a V in Task Manager like Vbox Headless.exe, etc). Once I did that, I was able to get this error to go away (the above 'vboxmanage startvm  ...etc...' solutions here did not work for me).

Answer (score 4):

If you have a settings window open for that box in the VirtualBox GUI, you may run into this error. Just close the settings window and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I've encounter the same error message today:

```
>me@myhost:~$ ps -ef | grep -i "vbox"

me  3064     1  0 08:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxXPCOMIPCD

me  3089     1  0 08:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC --auto-shutdown

me  3126  3089 27 08:51 ?        00:00:39 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxHeadless --comment RHEL5 64-bit desktop --startvm e5c598d8-1234-4003-a7c1-b9d8af15dfe7 --vrde config

me  3861  3415  0 08:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i vbox*
```

Gergely's answer solves it perfectly. It turned out that I've a crontab set at reboot to boot the virtual machine, which initiated the three VBox process shown above

```
me@myhost:~$ crontab -l

@reboot me /usr/bin/vboxmanage startvm "RHEL5 64-bit desktop" --type headless
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because **You reallocated the memory set for Virtual Box**
What you have to do to fix is: Restart The PC

Comment: vboxmanage did not work and killing vbox processes either; I was going to destroy the box but first I wanted to restart the system and give a last trial which turned the box on

Answer (score 0):

The only option that worked for me was to kill all the processes matching ps axl|grep -i vbox.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the apparent cause was a USB ethernet adapter that had been removed after suspending the machine. In my case,

```
vboxmanage startvm <vm-uuid> --type emergencystop
```

did not help. Instead, I received the confusing message that

> ```
> VBoxManage: error: The machine 'xyzzy' is not locked by a session
> ```

The true error was revealed by running

```
vboxmanage startvm <vm-uuid> --type gui
```

which returned

> ```
> VBoxManage: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'en9: USBPlug' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
> ```

Changing the network configuration to a different network adapter solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with VirtualBox 7.0.12 and Windows 11. Every time I attempt to turn on the computer, "Result Code: E_FAIL (0X80004005)" appears. I was unsuccessful in my attempt to initiate headless ***START* from the GUI. But the command

`VBoxHeadless --startvm <vm-uid>`

Revealed more details, which ultimately revealed the underlying cause.

VBoxHeadless.exe ****Failed to open release log (could not open file 'F:\LAB\VD\KuberBaba\Kubernetes\kuberWorkerNode2\Logs\VBox.log' (fOpen=0x282), VERR_ALREADY_EXISTS)****

Created one backup of the log and file deleted the original one.

[image: Sucessful start in headless mode]

Answer (score 0):

This is for Windows:
The Multipass.run stores the reference Virtual Images (VDI) in the location: C:\ProgramData\Multipass\cahce\virtualbox\vault\images These files are used to create the VMs.

The most probable reason that you received an error was even though the Ubuntu core image was downloaded the VM was not created.

The VMs are kept in the location: C:\ProgramData\Multipass\data\virtualbox\vault\instances

Every VM has a folder under instance.

In order to see a list instances you can use:

1. To get list of instannces: multipass list
2. To get a list of images that you can create: multipass find
3. To create a new instance: multipass launch [Image]

Once you create a new instance. You won't get that error.